# Renderizar con el metodo html.inner

Tags: javascript-objeto

Al intentar renderizar el siguiente codigo en un documento html , no se logra

```
let objDos = {
    Dental: [
      {
          HORA: "8:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "ANDREA ZUÑIGA",
          PACIENTE: "MARCELA RETAMAL",
          RUT: "11123425-6",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "MARIA PIA ZAÑARTU",
          PACIENTE: "ANGEL MUÑOZ",
          RUT: "9878789-2",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      },
      {
          HORA: "11:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "SCARLETT WITTING",
          PACIENTE: "MARIO KAST",
          RUT: "7998789-5",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "13:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "FRANCISCO VON TEUBER",
          PACIENTE: "KARIN FERNANDEZ",
          RUT: "18887662-K",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "13:30",
          ESPECIALISTA: "EDUARDO VIÑUELA",
          PACIENTE: "HUGO SANCHEZ",
          RUT: "17665461-4",
          PREVISION: "FONASA"
      },
      {
          HORA: "14:00",
          ESPECIALISTA: "RAQUEL VILLASECA",
          PACIENTE: "ANA SEPULVEDA",
          RUT: "14441281-0",
          PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
      }
    ]
    }
    let clientes = objDos.Dental;
for(item of clientes){
   let text = `<p>${item.HORA}, ${item.ESPECIALISTA}, ${item.PACIENTE}</p>`
   let  consultas
    consultas.push(text);
   document.getElementById("consultantes").innerHTML+=text;
}
```

Claro está que en el documento html tengo un div con un identificador "consultantes". Lo que no entiendo es la razón por la que no se renderiza o visualiza en el navegador.La consola indica errores, pero no sé la amnera de corregirlos.
Anteriormente he intentado visualizarla en el navegador , siguiendo otros procedimientos, pero no se ha podido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mayor problema que tienes es que estás tratando de hacer la función `push()` sobre una variable que no es un **array**. No comprendo lo que pretendías pero es lo que te está provocando el error.

Eliminando las líneas que hacen referencia a la variable `consulta` deberías poder insertar correctamente el texto en el **DOM**.

```js
let objDos = {
  Dental: [
    {
        HORA: "8:30",
        ESPECIALISTA: "ANDREA ZUÑIGA",
        PACIENTE: "MARCELA RETAMAL",
        RUT: "11123425-6",
        PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
    },
    {
        HORA: "11:00",
        ESPECIALISTA: "MARIA PIA ZAÑARTU",
        PACIENTE: "ANGEL MUÑOZ",
        RUT: "9878789-2",
        PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
    },
    {
        HORA: "11:30",
        ESPECIALISTA: "SCARLETT WITTING",
        PACIENTE: "MARIO KAST",
        RUT: "7998789-5",
        PREVISION: "FONASA"
    },
    {
        HORA: "13:00",
        ESPECIALISTA: "FRANCISCO VON TEUBER",
        PACIENTE: "KARIN FERNANDEZ",
        RUT: "18887662-K",
        PREVISION: "FONASA"
    },
    {
        HORA: "13:30",
        ESPECIALISTA: "EDUARDO VIÑUELA",
        PACIENTE: "HUGO SANCHEZ",
        RUT: "17665461-4",
        PREVISION: "FONASA"
    },
    {
        HORA: "14:00",
        ESPECIALISTA: "RAQUEL VILLASECA",
        PACIENTE: "ANA SEPULVEDA",
        RUT: "14441281-0",
        PREVISION: "ISAPRE"
    }
  ]
}

const clientes = objDos.Dental;

for(item of clientes){
    let text = `<p>${item.HORA}, ${item.ESPECIALISTA}, ${item.PACIENTE}</p>`;
    document.getElementById("consultantes").innerHTML += text;
}
```

```html
<div id="consultantes"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias . Ese era el problema